# MS SQL Server finding top 4 peak readings in a table and display as columns

Tags: sql-server

my data set

```
Date_Time   Load
7/24/17 12:00 AM    3987
7/24/17 1:00 AM 3748
7/24/17 2:00 AM 3608
7/24/17 3:00 AM 3526
7/24/17 4:00 AM 3493
7/24/17 5:00 AM 3545
7/24/17 6:00 AM 3683
7/24/17 7:00 AM 3827
7/24/17 8:00 AM 3942
7/24/17 9:00 AM 3956
7/24/17 10:00 AM    3985
7/24/17 11:00 AM    4000
7/24/17 12:00 PM    3917
7/24/17 1:00 PM 3834
7/24/17 2:00 PM 3901
7/24/17 3:00 PM 4132
7/24/17 4:00 PM 4388
7/24/17 5:00 PM 4497
7/24/17 6:00 PM 4675
7/24/17 7:00 PM 4713
7/24/17 8:00 PM 4743
7/24/17 9:00 PM 4704
7/24/17 10:00 PM    4540
7/24/17 11:00 PM    4227
```

what I need--desired output

```
Date_Time   Load          Peak-1    Peak-2  Peak-3  Peak-4
7/24/17 12:00 AM    3987                
7/24/17 1:00 AM 3748                
7/24/17 2:00 AM 3608                
7/24/17 3:00 AM 3526                
7/24/17 4:00 AM 3493                
7/24/17 5:00 AM 3545                
7/24/17 6:00 AM 3683                
7/24/17 7:00 AM 3827                
7/24/17 8:00 AM 3942                
7/24/17 9:00 AM 3956                
7/24/17 10:00 AM    3985                
7/24/17 11:00 AM    4000                
7/24/17 12:00 PM    3917                
7/24/17 1:00 PM 3834                
7/24/17 2:00 PM 3901                
7/24/17 3:00 PM 4132                
7/24/17 4:00 PM 4388                
7/24/17 5:00 PM 4497                
7/24/17 6:00 PM 4675                1
7/24/17 7:00 PM 4713        1       
7/24/17 8:00 PM 4743    1           
7/24/17 9:00 PM 4704            1   
7/24/17 10:00 PM    4540                
7/24/17 11:00 PM    4227
```

here is what I wrote

this is way messy
select date_time, system_load   FROM dbo.Loads E1
WHERE E1.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E1.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day) 
    AND (4-3) = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.system_load)) From  dbo.Loads E2
    Where
 E2.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E2.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day)
 AND 
        E2.system_load > E1.system_load)
        UNION
        select date_time, system_load   FROM dbo.Loads E1
WHERE E1.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E1.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day) 
    AND (4-2) = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.system_load)) From  dbo.Loads E2
    Where
 E2.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E2.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day)
 AND 
        E2.system_load > E1.system_load)
        UNION
        select date_time, system_load   FROM dbo.Loads E1
WHERE E1.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E1.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day) 
    AND (4-1) = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.system_load)) From  dbo.Loads E2
    Where
 E2.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E2.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day)
 AND 
        E2.system_load > E1.system_load)
        UNION
        select date_time, system_load   FROM dbo.Loads E1
WHERE E1.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E1.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day) 
    AND (4-4) = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.system_load)) From  dbo.Loads E2
    Where
 E2.Date_Time >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and E2.date_time< DATEADD(day, +0, convert(date, GETDATE ()))-- Previous Day)
 AND 
        E2.system_load > E1.system_load) 
        ORDER BY SYSTEM_LOAD DESC

Comment: Show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Basically I need to mark 1st highest, 2nd highest, 3rd highest and 4th highest in the corresponding columns. Haven't got anything working yet.

Comment: Then it's likely too early to ask this here. Do some research, make an attempt, show us a little effort.  If you're simply looking for someone to write your query from scratch, then consider hiring a developer.

Comment: this is way messy

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you a column counting the highest load as 1,  next as 2 etc

I suggest you wrap it up into a sub query, and then use four instances of  `case when load_rank =
Xxx then 1 end` to put a 1 for each column (xxx is a number from 1 to 4) - this an exercise for you to have a go. We'll be here to help

```
SELECT
  Date_time, load, row_number() over(partition by convert(date, date_time) order by load desc) as load_rank
FROM 
  Table
ORDER BY date_time
```

Comment: sir, I get error [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.(42000,156) SELECT
  Date_time, load, row_number() over(partition by convert(date, date_time order by load desc  deaf) as load_rank
FROM 
  Table
ORDER BY date_time

Comment: Sorry, iPhone autocorrect causing a typo in the code and a bracket was missing. Try now

Comment: Amazing.. you are really a STAR. You have optimized my 10 lines of code to just one single line.. Thank you sir, This has been a successful forum just because of such talented contributors as you.